# How can I get an Ecto.DateTime value representing the current time?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to get an `Ecto.DateTime` value that represents the current time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `DateTime.utc_now |> Ecto.DateTime.cast` works, there is a simpler way with `Ecto.DateTime.utc`

It's basically the same but with a different default precision:

```
iex(30)> DateTime.utc_now |> Ecto.DateTime.cast
{:ok, #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-27 19:55:38.542000>}

iex(31)> Ecto.DateTime.utc
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-27 19:55:45>

iex(32)> Ecto.DateTime.utc(:usec)
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-27 19:55:48.162000>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `DateTime.utc_now` and `cast` it.

```
{:ok, datetime} = DateTime.utc_now |> Ecto.DateTime.cast
```

Comment: Why the casting? What's wrong with `Ecto.DateTime.utc`?

Comment: @JonasDellinger Nothing's wrong with it - I just missed it somehow in the docs. :) Thanks.